# Maven can't download dependencies from central repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3

when I launch the build in Eclipse, maven can't download the dependencies from the central repository :

```
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.132.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
org.eclipse.aether.transfer.MetadataTransferException: Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.132.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.MetadataTransportListener.transferFailed (MetadataTransportListener.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveMetadata (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver.resolveMissingPluginVersions (LifecyclePluginResolver.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.TransferFailedException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.132.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:1069)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveMetadata (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver.resolveMissingPluginVersions (LifecyclePluginResolver.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.132.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:159)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:825)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:986)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveMetadata (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver.resolveMissingPluginVersions (LifecyclePluginResolver.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0 (Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect (Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect (Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket (SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect (DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect (PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute (MainClientExec.java:381)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:237)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.execute (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:825)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:986)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.wagon.shared.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData (AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:963)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream (StreamWagon.java:126)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer (StreamWagon.java:88)
    at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get (StreamWagon.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter$GetTaskRunner.run (WagonTransporter.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.execute (WagonTransporter.java:435)
    at org.eclipse.aether.transport.wagon.WagonTransporter.get (WagonTransporter.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$GetTaskRunner.runTask (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:453)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$TaskRunner.run (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector$DirectExecutor.execute (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:583)
    at org.eclipse.aether.connector.basic.BasicRepositoryConnector.get (BasicRepositoryConnector.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$ResolveTask.run (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:593)
    at org.eclipse.aether.util.concurrency.RunnableErrorForwarder$1.run (RunnableErrorForwarder.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver$1.execute (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolve (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultMetadataResolver.resolveMetadata (DefaultMetadataResolver.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveMetadata (DefaultRepositorySystem.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolveFromRepository (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.version.internal.DefaultPluginVersionResolver.resolve (DefaultPluginVersionResolver.java:94)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecyclePluginResolver.resolveMissingPluginVersions (LifecyclePluginResolver.java:86)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.calculateExecutionPlan (DefaultLifecycleExecutionPlanCalculator.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.BuilderCommon.resolveBuildPlan (BuilderCommon.java:97)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

here is what my settings.xml in maven install looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <pluginGroups>
    <!-- pluginGroup
     | Specifies a further group identifier to use for plugin lookup.
    <pluginGroup>com.your.plugins</pluginGroup>
    -->
  </pluginGroups>

  <!-- proxies
   | This is a list of proxies which can be used on this machine to connect to the network.
   | Unless otherwise specified (by system property or command-line switch), the first proxy
   | specification in this list marked as active will be used.
   |-->
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>optional1</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <username></username>
      <password></password>
      <host>proxy_url</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

    <proxy>
      <id>optional2</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>https</protocol>
      <username>user here</username>
      <password>password here</password>
      <host>proxy_url</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>

  </proxies>


  <servers>

  </servers>


  <mirrors>


  </mirrors>


  <profiles>

  </profiles>

</settings>
```

I've tried changing proxies in settings.xml to add the proxy configurations but did not work, Also I have tried to add a mirror tag under `<mirrors>` to connect to the central maven repository only through *http* like this

```
  <mirror>
        <id>central-no-ssl</id>
        <name>Central without ssl</name>
        <url>http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
```

but it did not work.
How can I solve this ?

Comment: "connection timed out" often means you simply cannot reach the other host on the network. Is there any firewall in the way? Do you have to use a proxy to reach the internet?

Comment: Don't edit the settings.xml in your maven install. Instead, put your own settings.xml into the `.m2` directory.

Comment: @Henry I am behind two firewalls and a proxy, but the same link that maven is trying to get to works just fine from the browsers

Comment: I suggest, you talk to your network administrator how to reach the internet.

Comment: @Henry  the same link that maven is trying to get to works just fine from the browsers, so thought may be there is something wrong with my own Maven configuration

Comment: Yes, you have to configure the proxy. But I cannot help with that, I don't know how your network looks like. What's the address of the proxy? Which authentication does it need?

Comment: make sure that you use this configuration settings file, maybe Eclipse is not using it

Comment: "the same link that maven is trying to get to works just fine from the browsers" This does not necessarily mean anything. I had this a couple of times in a company network. Browsers are sometimes allowed to do more than other programs, i.e. if you have the "Internet Explorer" user-agent, your requests are answered, otherwise not.